# Example of iOS app using Tesseract lib ?

Tags: ios, iphone, tesseract

Is anyone known an iOs application which using the Tesseract OCR technology ? 
(https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)

There is just one example in the credits (ScanBizCards)...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Posts should not be asking for examples of code without a clear problem to solve. If you have an issue of your use of Tesseract lib then by all means post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are trying to use OCR. I would recommend using google drive/doc api for that. You don't need a third party lib like Tesseract instead you could use easy integration provided by the google api for Android and iOS. However, if your system does it at your server then Tesseract is an option, although the api also has the java/javascript/python/php etc based option for backend systems.

This link will guide you more: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples

Comment: The point is just about examples of iOS app currently using the Tesseract lib. That's it

Comment: So here you go: Posts should not be asking for examples of code without a clear problem to solve. If you have an issue of your use of Tesseract lib then by all means post your code - brimble2010